# Android studio - Sync gradle takes too long when a lot of flavors (>70)

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, synchronization

I have an android project with :
**2 flavorDimensions** (**customer** and **mode**)
I have **more than 70 customers** and **2 types of mode : normal and extra**.
All customers are "normal" and only one customer is "extra".

I'm using variantFilter { variant -> to limit number of build variants when syncing my project to avoid useless customers combined with mode "extra" because there is only one customer with this mode.

For example :

- Customer1NormalRelease
- Customer2NormalRelease
- Customer3NormalRelease
- Customer4ExtraRelease
- Customer5NormalRelease
- Customer6NormalRelease
- ...

The problem is when I'm trying to sync gradle with a lot of variants, it takes huge time for each variant.

When Inspecting build : Resolve dependencies of :appCustomer1NormalReleaseCompileClasspath takes 8minutes.
Moreover, I don't understand why appCustomer1NormalReleaseCompileClasspath try to resolve dependencies for others variants because they are totaly different (no sense).
My dependencies are global to the project, no variant specific dependencies.

I'm using :

- Android studio 3.1.3
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
- distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
- org.gradle.daemon=true
- org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
- Gradle global settings : offline work
- all libraries are remote and I have only one local library

Any idea ?

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I found where was the issue !

I'm using OneSignal to push notifications

I'm using gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin in my build.gradle (app) to ensure correct behaviors.

I just changed

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.10.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.11.2'
```

and the build was super fast. 2 minutes to build all flavors :O

So If you have too a problem like this, check your gradle plugins !!!